# Referencing a text-box through an object name in VisualBasic.NET

Tags: sql, arrays, vb.net, object

How can I possibly use the value of an object (e.g. a string), to then reference to the name of a text-box on a form in Visual Basic .net? I'm hoping to be able to grab information from a SQL database and put them in corresponding text-boxes, based on their names on the form (e.g. put the information for the field fSynopsis in the text-box txtSynopsis.Text).

The code below is what I'm using at the moment.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvResults.CellMouseClick
    ' Set values in the text boxes to both corresponding to the film.

    Dim strFields() As String = {"fSynopsis", "fGenre", "fSynopsis", "fAgeRating", "fActorsActresses", "fWebRating", "fNoReservations", "fWeeksRunning"}
    'Create an array containing the names of the fields in the database.

    Dim Con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ApplicationData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    Con.Open() 'Open the connection
    Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand(StringBuilderCommand("fAgeRating", "Films", dgvResults.CurrentCell.Value, "fName"), Con) 'Create a string by calling the StringBuilderCommand to combine the parameters together with quotes.

    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim Rdr As OleDbDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Dim intCount As Integer = 0 ' Create a loop variable.
    Do While Rdr.Read() ' While this statement is 'TRUE', e.g. there is a valid record.

        strResult = "txt" & strFields(intCount).Replace("f", "") 'Remove any instances of 'f', e.g. the prefix of the string.

        strResult.Text = Rdr.Item(strFields(intCount).ToString)
        'Set the text-box to the correct value from the database.
        ' This will allow me to go through several text boxes, and grab their corresponding  values from the database.

        intCount += 1
    Loop
```

I'd really appreciate any help available, thank-you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Code.

```
 CType( Me.Controls("strResult"),TextBox).Text = Rdr.Item(strFields(intCount).ToString)
```